# How to increment the value in the array of objects based on highest value and parameters and get result using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of object, based on condition increment the values using javascript

Below list, when two parameters are passed, `updateValue` and `uid`

-> if `id` and `uid` same, update the value

-> if `id !== uid` and `val >= updateVal` and `val <= highest value in the list`
then increment the value.

-> else return val

```
const list = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 3, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, val: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, val: 2, color: 'indigo' },
];

var uid = 13, var updateVal=2
```

Tried

```
var result=[];
var listcount = list.filter(i => i.val !== null).length;
//update the value based on same id
var updateList = list.map(e => ({...e,
    e.val = res.id === uid ? updateValue : e.val
  })
// increment the val with the updatedList
var result = updateList.map(res => ({ 
     ...res,
     val =  (res.id !== uid && res.val >= updateVal && res.val <= listcount) ?
      (res.val || 0) + 1 : res.val
   })

}
```

Expected Output

```
[
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, val: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, val: 3, color: 'indigo' },
];
```

if the list is

```
list1 = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 5, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, val: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, val: 2, color: 'indigo' },
];
var uid = 44, var updateVal=2
```

then result should be

```
[
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 6, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, val: 2, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, val: 3, color: 'indigo' },
];
```

Comment: What is `res` in the first map?

Comment: Your maximum value in the list is not `listcount`.  In the sample list it is, lucky, but in your last expected result, the maximum would be 6, not 4.  Fix your `highest value in the list`.

Comment: Your code is full of basic syntax errors (unmatched parentheses, misnamed variables, etc.). These make it really difficult for people to know what problem you're actually encountering, or propose fixes.. Please fix those syntax problems first. If one of those syntax errors is what you can't figure out how to fix, ask a question about that specifically, with as little code as possible to reproduce that issue.

Answer (score 0):

We first can find highest number by looping over array and then we can use these values to determine if we need to increment or return the value as it is.

You can try something like below

```
const list = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 3, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, val: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, val: 2, color: 'indigo' },
];

let highest = 0;
list.map(e => {
  if (Number(e.val) > highest) {
    highest = e.val;
  }
});

function updateList(list, updateVal, uid) {
  const result = list.map(res => ({ 
    ...res,
    res.val = (res.id !== uid && res.val >= updateVal && res.val < highest) ?
      (res.val || 0) + 1 : res.val
  });
  return result;
}

const updateVal = 2;
const uid = 44;
const result = updateList(list, updateVal, uid);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, can i ask like if list has missing sequence then have it as highest else the highest value. can help please

Comment: The highest variable above will give you highest value in the list no matter what the sequence is..

Comment: thanks for reply, i updated the answer and wrote in comments, can help if possible